# Cannot log in to new PostgreSQL database on Linux

Tags: postgresql

I just installed PostgreSQL 9.6 on Centos 7 and ran the following commands:

```
[root@centos-server ~ ]sudo su - postgres
Last login: Sat Apr 20 07:26:35 UTC 2019 on pts/1
-bash-4.2$ psql
psql (9.6.12)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE ROLE mydbuser WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'secret' VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE mydb WITH ENCODING 'UNICODE' LC_COLLATE 'C' LC_CTYPE 'C' TEMPLATE template0;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO mydbuser;
GRANT
postgres=# \q
```

However, when I try to log in to the database, I get an error:

```
[root@centos-server ~ ]# psql -h localhost -U mydbuser -d mydb -W
Password for user mydbuser:
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "mydbuser"
```

Please assist!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line as the first line of *pg_hba.conf*. It allows access to all databases for all users with an encrypted password:

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

and restart PostgreSQL service:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql-9.6.service
```